# Sorting out a map of structures

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, struct

I am working on a Twitter-like application. And one of the functions I want to implement is printing the tweets of the users you follow. The thing is that these tweets(I called them "baa"s) must be in order according to an ID( the largest ID must be shown the first and the smallest the last one). So the problem is how to implement this in an efficient way.

I have all the messages stored in a map with Username as primary key. Each line of the map is a vector of messages, where messges is a Struct which has the Baa, Time(in which it was written) and the ID. The message struct is defined like this:

```
struct message{
    static unsigned int last_id;
    unsigned int id;
    std::string baa;
    std::string timestamp;

    message(const std::string& recvbuf_baa,const std::string& a_timestamp) :
    baa(recvbuf_baa), timestamp(a_timestamp), id(++last_id)
  {
  }
};
```

An the map for data and followers like this:

```
map<std::string,std::vector<message *> > data;
map<std::string,std::vector<string> > followers;
```

An additional difficulty is that I need to make this in the sever because the client just prints what he receives, so we have to send the "Baa"s in order. I currently have this code for sending all the Baas of a single user to the client (which prints in descendent way using reverse iterator):

```
            for(auto it2=data[usrn].rbegin(); it2!=data[usrn].rend(); it2++)
            {
                    MessageSerializer serializer(**it2,usrn);
                    char* buffer = new char[serializer.RequiredBufferSize()];
                    serializer.Serialize(buffer,usrn);
                    iSendResult = send( ClientSocket, buffer,serializer.RequiredBufferSize(), 0 );
            }
```

I can print all the followers timeline in this way, but the tweets are ordered in ascendent ID order(1,2,3...) instead of descendent(...3,2,1)

```
for(auto it=followers[usrn].begin(); it!=followers[usrn].end(); it++)
                    {
                        for(auto it2=data[*it].rbegin(); it2!=data[*it].rend(); it2++)
                        {
                            MessageSerializer serializer(**it2,*it);
                            char* buffer = new char[serializer.RequiredBufferSize()];
                            serializer.Serialize(buffer,*it);
                            iSendResult = send( ClientSocket, buffer, serializer.RequiredBufferSize(), 0 );
                        }
                    }
```

I dont know how is the most efficient way of printing all follower's tweets in descendent order. Maybe there is an eficcient way of accessing the struct of messages in order according to the ID, or maybe allocating memory and storing (with ID as Key parameter) just the structs of messages of the users you follow, etc.

Which is the best way to implement this function?